# Why arXiv version disappeared from Google Scholar profile once journal version published

Tags: publications, journals, arxiv, google-scholar

Based on a question I asked previously [Uploading a revised version of published journal article on arXiv](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87321/uploading-a-revised-version-of-published-journal-article-on-arxiv) I uploaded a new version on arXiv which included minor corrections and enhancement to published journal version.  Once journal article came online the pre-print version disappeared from my google scholar profile. As the current version of arXiv is advanced version of journal article I want arXiv version to appear on my profile.
How can I make arXiv version to apear in my profile?

Comment: I side with Google on the position that the archival version is definitive and that it should supersede arXiv.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't disappeared, it is only grouped together. If you click to your article in Google Scholar, at the end of the page, you'll find "All N versions". Click on it, you will find your ArXiv versions, and some other mirror sites that you may not aware.

Next time, if you want your ArXiv version to be listed separately, change the title to "My awesome paper (extended version)". When the titles are different, the article will not be grouped together.

Note: it's never a good idea to inflate your paper count in Google Scholar with different versions of the same paper.

Comment: This is not the case for me! My first version on Arxiv (having a different title with over 10 citations on google scholar) got removed completely which is insane! Now only the published version is displayed and all the citations with the previous title of my Arxiv version have also disappeared! Google Scholar is definitely the worst Google service ever!