# Does anybody link the compete work in Arxiv?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, arxiv, online-publication

Here is the scenario, can you give me your idea about 2 things?

A conference paper is published, you submit it to ArXiv. You journalize the paper (with a modified title and added material) and publish it.

A) Should you get a new arXiv link for it?

Let's assume you get a new arXiv link for it.

B) Can you update the fist ArXiv submission and indicate in the first page, in the footnote, that the complete work has been published in a journal and is available in the second arXiv link?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the operation of specific sites are outside of our scope and should be addressed to the help system of the website.

Comment: You do not need a new link. You simply update the existing paper (if needed) and add the journal and is available outside of arXiv.

Comment: I think arXiv is so widely used that best practices for its use are a significant part of publishing one's research (in relevant fields).  I vote to reopen.

Comment: I think this question is mostly answered by [Uploading a revised version of published journal article on arXiv](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/87321/546).

Comment: This question is not really a duplicate of the one linked by @scaahu, and the academic best practise of how to use the arXiv is certainly on-topic here. The question should be reopened.